# Presto SQL - Expand by all dates/group combinations

Tags: sql, presto

I have a table that includes dates, groups and values:

```
date         group   subgroup value
2018-01-01   A       1        20
2018-01-04   A       1        70
2018-01-06   A       1        80
```

I would like to fill the dates that are missing by the group/subgroup combinations like this:

```
date         group   subgroup value
2018-01-01   A       1        20
2018-01-02   A       1        0
2018-01-03   A       1        0
2018-01-04   A       1        70
2018-01-05   A       1        0
2018-01-06   A       1        80
```

One way to do this is by cross joining to a table with a sequence of dates and then left joining back to the original table, however, I would like to avoid doing so as I have a large number of combinations all with different min and max dates and this type of solution would be rather "non-performant".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want a different sequence for each group/subgroup combination then this is tricky.

However, in PrestoDB, you can use [`sequence()`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#sequence) and [`unnest()`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest) which are almost as handy as `generate_series()` (okay, not really, but they do the same thing).

The query would look like this:

```
select gs.group, gs.subgroup, d.dte, coalesce(t.value, 0)
from (select group, subgroup, min(date) as mind, max(date) as maxd,
             sequence(min(date), max(date)) as date_arr
      from t
      group by group, subgroup
     ) gs cross join
     unnest(date_arr) d(dte) left join
     t
     on t.group = gs.grp and t.subgroup = gs.subgroup and t.date = d.dte
order by gs.group, gs.subgroup, d.dte;
```

Comment: Great answer! This is exactly why we made sequence() work for dates.

Comment: Gordon,

Thanks for your help.

I assume the unnest is added to deal with the sequence returning an array instead of a date column, however, I am having issues with the t assignment.  "t" seems to be assigned within the subquery, however, the query calls t outside of the subquery where it is not assigned which is giving me an error in this case.  There is also a reference to "d" which I don't see assigned either.

Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: @ericbrownaustin . . . `t` is just a shorthand for your table name and alias.  `d` is assigned as the alias for the `unnest()`.

Comment: @DavidPhillips . . . You could have just implemented Postgres's `generate_series()`.